# Sorting an array with hundreds of different names and values

Tags: php, sorting, asort

I'm making a program that tracks hundreds of users, grabs their experience (stores it), and then grabs it again on demand once the designated time for tracking is over.  What I'm trying to do is sort the amount of gained experience, while keeping it in association with the name, and then outputting the experience gained from highest to lowest.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
display();

function display() {
    $participants = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
    sort($participants);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($participants); $i++) {
        $starting = getStarting($participants[$i]);
        $ending = getEnding($participants[$i]);
        $gained = $ending - $starting;
    }
}

function getStarting($name) {
    $a = "a";
    return $name == $a ? 304 : 4;
}

function getEnding($name) {
    $a = "a";
    return $name == $a ? 23 : 34;
}
```

So, I'm trying to make it so that if I were to print a variable, then 'a' would be first (because, as you can see, I made it so 'a' is the only 'person' that has gained more experience than the others'), then 'b-e' would follow it, alphabetically.  It currently sorts it alphabetically before any data is collected, so I'm assuming all I'll have to do is sort the gained experience.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain what it is you're trying to do? Start with some "before" and "after" data. Your code example doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to put the values into a multidimensional array, then use usort():

```
function score_sort($a,$b) {
  // This function compares $a and $b
  // $a[0] is participant name
  // $a[1] is participant score
  if($a[1] == $b[1]) {
    return strcmp($a[0],$b[0]);  // Sort by name if scores are equal
  } else {
    return $a[1] < $b[1] ? -1 : 1;  // Sort by score
  }
}

function display() {
  $participants = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");

  // Create an empty array to store results
  $participant_scores = array();  

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($participants); $i++) {
    $starting = getStarting($participants[$i]);
    $ending = getEnding($participants[$i]);
    $gained = $ending - $starting;
    // Push the participant and score to the array 
    $participant_scores[] = array($participants[$i], $gained);
  }

  // Sort the array
  usort($participant_scores, 'score_sort');

  // Display the results
  foreach($participant_scores as $each_score) {
    sprintf("Participant %s has score %i\n", $each_score[0], $each_score[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: That works just like I want, thanks!  One problem, though.  I forgot to include that more user data was grabbed, meaning that there's more variables (`$startingLevel`, `$currentLevel`, and `$levelsGained`) which also need to be provided in the output of the program, as well as the `$starting` and `$ending` experience.  They don't need to be sorted in any way, just associated with the participant.  Could I achieve this by just adding more parameters and then using `$each_score[2]` and so on? (there's a total of 8 things that need to be included in the output, 7 of which are participant related)

Comment: Yeah, you can absolutely do this.  If you're storing a whole bunch of different data in the array, though, I'd recommend using text values for your array keys rather than numeric values.  So, in the display function:
$participant_scores[] = array('participant' => $participants[$i], 'gained' => $gained, 'other_value' => $other_value);
and in the usort function, use $a['participant'] instead of $a[0] and $a['gained'] instead of $a[1].  It'll probably make things easier for you, down the road.

Comment: If I do that, score_sort no longer works, right?  How could I make it so that it allows the extra keys or takes the keys instead of the value?

Comment: Also another thing that I noticed, I need the most score gained to be at the top, this puts it at the bottom.  I've searched for a reverse usort() but I couldn't find one.  Any way to do this?

Comment: for reversing, just switch 1 and -1 in: return $a[1] < $b[1] ? -1 : 1;